# How to fix wierd denoise

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I want an good looking render and this comes out, it seems like the denoise is not working properly in not enough light, but I want the scene to be dark

Does anybody know how to fix this?

- Cycles- gpu
- Noise tr. 0.05 - samples 4000
- Dnse - Optix, Albedo and Normal

[image: screen shot]

Comment: The high noise threshold might mean that low-light areas are not getting enough samples, so the light values aren't properly weighted in the denoise pass.

Answer (score 0):

Denoising is working properly, but there is only so much it can do. It has limits. You need to increase samples or optimize the scene to render faster. At the moment it seems you have only one light source so there is not much you can optimize. Maybe try to make sure you have as little geometry in the mesh emitting light as possible, because the more faces it has, the more complex the calculations get. [Light portals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/light_settings.html#area-lights) could be helpful if you had light coming from the environment(HDRI lighting).

Comment: well thanks that helped, I just aded more light and took it down in photoshop, thanks